# Can't Reset array to 0

Tags: c, arrays, reset

Its not make all the array 0 and I cant find why help please
 the last number in `arr_temp2` is garbage but the one before it is 0, but i  in the penultimate 27

`big=10 small=7`
 I can use only basic function (for , if , while)

```
 int arr_temp[big_size+small_size];
 int arr_temp1[(big_size+small_size+2)];
 int arr_temp2[(big_size+small_size+1)];

 for (j=0; j<big_size+small_size; j++)
 {
    arr_temp[j]=0;
 }

  for (t=0;t<(sizeof(arr_temp1)/sizeof(int));++t)
  {
     arr_temp1[t]=0;
  } 


 for (z=0;z<(sizeof(arr_temp2)/sizeof(int)); ++z)
 {
    arr_temp2[z]=0;
 }
```

Comment: I pasted the code shown into a skeleton program, ran it, and inspected the arrays in the debugger after the third loop terminated.  All three were properly filled with zeroes.  Your problem is not with the code shown.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) instead:

```
memset(arr_temp1, 0, sizeof(arr_temp1));
```

Or if you pass the array to a function, so it has decayed a pointer:

```
memset(arr_temp1, 0, sizeof(arr_temp1[0]) * (big_size+small_size+2));
```

Answer (score 3):

<strike>To initialize all the elements of arrays to `0` you can do it simply as</strike>

```
int arr_temp[big_size+small_size] = {0};
int arr_temp1[(big_size+small_size+2)] = {0};
int arr_temp2[(big_size+small_size+1)] = {0};
```

*Note here that I presumed that you are aware of variable length arrays (allowed in C99) and `big_size` and `small_size` initialized before declaring these arrays (which is a required condition for VLAs).*

My previous answer was wrong. VLAs can't be initialized that way.

You are doing right. No problem with that. I tested it with the code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int big_size = 4;
    int small_size = 2;

    int arr_temp[big_size+small_size];
    int arr_temp1[(big_size+small_size+2)];
    int arr_temp2[(big_size+small_size+1)];

     for (int j=0; j < big_size+small_size; j++)
     {
         arr_temp[j]=0;
         printf("%d", arr_temp[j]);
     }
     printf("\n\n");

     for (int t=0; t < (signed)(sizeof(arr_temp1)/sizeof(int)); ++t)
     {
         arr_temp1[t]=0;
         printf("%d", arr_temp1[t]);
     }
     printf("\n\n");

     for (int z=0;z<(signed)(sizeof(arr_temp2)/sizeof(int)); ++z)
     {
         arr_temp2[z]=0;
         printf("%d", arr_temp2[z]);
     }
     return 0;
}
```

and getting the output

```
000000

00000000

0000000
```

I casted `sizeof` operator with `unsigned` because it returns `size_t` (unsigned) type. Comparing `signed` and unsigned type could be dangerous.

Comment: I do not understand what are you saying. Could you rephrase your words?

Comment: I think variable-length array and should not be initialized specified.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY; You saved me mate :). This was a blunder. O__o